# Passing state from child to parent in React; child has separate state

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have three components, from outermost to innermost: `App` => `Welcome` => `SearchBar`. There's a state defined in `App` and `SearchBar`, but what I want is to get the user-inputted data in SearchBar and display that in a "Results" page. As such, I'm trying to update the state in `SearchBar` and have that simultaneously update the state in `App`, so that I can pass that data on to another component that's a child of `App` (e.g. `Results`). I have the following code, but it's only updating the state in  `SearchBar` and not that in `App`.

(I've looked at some examples where the child (in this case `SearchBar`) doesn't have its own state, but in this case I think it's necessary since I'm tracking user input. I may be wrong though.)

```
// App.js
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: "" };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      value: event.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="AppContainer">
          <Route
            exact
            path="/"
            render={props => <SearchBar handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />}
          />
...

// Welcome.js
export default class Welcome extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchBar handleSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit} />
      </div>
...

// SearchBar.js
export default class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: "" };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search..."
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          value={this.state.value}
        />
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Then again, I'm quite new to React so this might not be a pattern that you're supposed to use. In any case, I would appreciate advice on how to best solve this.

Comment: Hi mbj, were you able to find a solution to your question? I updated my answer with the updated code to help with your follow-up comments. Let me know if that helps :)

Comment: Yeah it works great. I didn't want to accept one answer because they're both great, but thank you very much!

Comment: That's understandable :)! Appreciate the follow-up. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've already defined a `handleSubmit()` event-handler in `App.js` and passed it all the way down to your `SearchBar.js` component. You can extrapolate the data you need by giving the input tag in your SearchBar a name prop.

```
class Searchbar extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: ""
  };

  handleOnChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      value: e.target.value
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit}>
        <input
          onChange={this.handleOnChange}
          value={this.state.value}
          name="search"
        />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Then in `App.js` handleSubmit handler, target that `name` prop to get the `value` in the input.

```
  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
       value: e.target.search.value
    })
  };
```

This will likely have the least amount of re-renders.

### Edit:

Yes we can totally display a new component upon submitting the form. We just need the help of a second state-value like `displayResults` or `displayComponent` then by using a simple if-check, we'll just toggle what components to show.
See working example: [Code Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-silence-v3wck)

Comment: you need to have `id="search"` in `input` for `e.target.search.value` to work.

Comment: @codekaizer seems to work fine with the `name` prop. https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-silence-v3wck. Although I do agree that id might be syntactically more useful :)

Comment: Yeah this is it! (Sorry for the late reply.) I don't understand why it needs a name prop though?

Comment: Also, is there a way to display a different component after hitting submit, instead of having the page remain the same? The updated state will be passed into this new component

Comment: @mbj. No worries! You need the `name` prop so that you can target the specific input in the form. That way we can get the input value. Also, yes we can totally display a new component upon submitting the form. We just need the help of a second state-value like "displayResults" or "displayComponent" then by using a simple if-check, we'll just toggle what components to show. Try this example here:https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-silence-v3wck

Answer (score 1):

In `SearchBar` component you should pass `state` value directly to `handleSubmit` function as,

```
<form onSubmit={(e)=>{e.preventDefault(); this.props.handleSubmit(this.state.value)}}>
```

In `App` component your `handleSubmit` function should be,

```
handleSubmit(inputValue) {
    this.setState({
      value: inputValue
    });
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vmxxa5)

Comment: why can't the OP use the event passed by `onSubmit`?

Comment: When we use `e.target.value` in setState, due to async nature of setState the event gets nullified and we don't get any value. We need to capture the value in a variable before calling setSate. So it is always better to directly pass the value.

Comment: This doesn't work, it refreshes the page after I click submit and the state is lost

Comment: Can you post your updated code so that I can see what is wrong?

Comment: What do you mean? I basically added the changes you suggested

Comment: Here's a codesandbox using the above solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-dawn-o7ytp. Curious to see your method!

Comment: Check the updated answer and Demo link, my bad I forgot to add `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: Ah I see, and based on what you said earlier I think it makes a lot of sense! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Earlier I tested with simple input directly.